# SQL syntax error when reading data from database

Tags: python, mysql, syntax, syntax-error

Running the code shown here, I get a SQL syntax error, couldn't find the reason:

```
startEpoch = 1623331800#july 10 7PM ePOCH
EndEpoch = 1624195800#july 20 7PM ePOCH

query = "SELECT `Machine`,`Epoch`,`Time`,`STATE` FROM MSC where `Epoch`>=" + str(startEpoch) + "and `Epoch`<=" + str(EndEpoch) + ";"
df = pd.read_sql(query, db)
df.head(3)
```

Error:

> DatabaseError: Execution failed on SQL 'SELECT `Machine`,`Epoch`,`Time`,`STATE` FROM MSC where `Epoch`>=1623331800and `Epoch`<=1624195800;':
>
> 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`Epoch`<=1624195800' at line 1

Comment: `1623331800and`. Notice anything?

Comment: ops, my bad !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AND` keyword concat with the value **1623331800and**

Try the below:

```
startEpoch = 1623331800#july 10 7PM ePOCH
EndEpoch = 1624195800#july 20 7PM ePOCH

query = "SELECT `Machine`,`Epoch`,`Time`,`STATE` FROM MSC where `Epoch`>= " + str(startEpoch) + " and `Epoch`<= " + str(EndEpoch) + ";"
df = pd.read_sql(query, db)
df.head(3)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on SQL 'SELECT Machine,Epoch,Time,STATE FROM MSC where Epoch>=**1623331800and** Epoch<=1624195800;':
```

behind the condition of the epoch field, I think the error will resolve if you add 1 space before the "and" character.